# Regex to split a string in Python 3.7

Tags: python, regex, excel

I'm trying to split a sequence of non-regular strings that I read in a python program from excel files. I am using Regex101.com for testing and I partially have succeeded in doing it:
My sample:

```
Barber #1-1 Daily Prod. - Pumping unit  
Barbee #1-3 Daily Prod. - Plunger Lift  
Barbee #1-5 Daily Prod. = Coil Tubing  
Barbee #1-3 Daily Prod. - Plunger  
Barbee #1-5 Daily Prod.w/ coil tubing  
Porter GU #1 Well #2 Daily Prod.  
Barber GU #1 Well #1 Daily Prod.  
Bogel #1-2 Daily Prod. w/ plunger
```

My regex:
`(.*)\sDaily Prod\.(.*$)`

I am getting this answer select group1 and group2:

```
Barber #1-1 - Pumping unit  
Barbee #1-3 - Plunger Lift  
Barbee #1-5 = Coil Tubing  
Barbee #1-3 - Plunger  
Barbee #1-5w/ coil tubing  
Porter GU #1 Well #2  
Barber GU #1 Well #1  
Bogel #1-2 w/ plunger
```

and I would like to have:

```
Barber #1-1 Pumping unit  
Barbee #1-3 Plunger Lift  
Barbee #1-5 Coil Tubing  
Barbee #1-3 Plunger  
Barbee #1-5 coil tubing  
Porter GU #1 Well #2  
Barber GU #1 Well #1  
Bogel #1-2 plunger
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this expression might likely work:

```
(.*)\sDaily Prod\.(\s*[-=w\/]+\s*)?(.*)
```

Here, we have an optional group:

```
(\s*[-=w\/]+\s*)?
```

which we collect our undesired chars and spaces, then we make a replacement with $1 and $3.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/trZvzU/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.*)\sDaily Prod\.(\s*[-=w\/]+\s*)?(.*)"

test_str = ("Barber #1-1 Daily Prod. - Pumping unit\n"
    "Barbee #1-3 Daily Prod. - Plunger Lift\n"
    "Barbee #1-5 Daily Prod. = Coil Tubing\n"
    "Barbee #1-3 Daily Prod. - Plunger\n"
    "Barbee #1-5 Daily Prod.w/ coil tubing\n"
    "Porter GU #1 Well #2 Daily Prod.\n"
    "Barber GU #1 Well #1 Daily Prod.\n"
    "Bogel #1-2 Daily Prod. w/ plunger")

subst = "\\1 \\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emma. Yes. That works perfectly. This regex stuff makes me blind sometimes. Thanks. And thanks to GSD for editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also match what you want to remove and replace with an empty string:

```
\sDaily Prod\.(?:\s*(?:[-=]|w/))?
```

**Explanation**

- `\sDaily Prod\.` Match whitespace char, Daily Prod and dot
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[-=]` Match `-` or `=`
    - `|` Or
    - `w/` Match literally
  - `)` Close non capturing group
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XBkKE2/1)